# Can Samsung patch security faults on their devices by an update?

Tags: samsung, security

There was an exploit that turns Samsung Galaxy phones into remote bugging devices (reference: [ArsTechnica](http://arstechnica.com/security/2015/06/new-exploit-turns-samsung-galaxy-phones-into-remote-bugging-devices/))

> As many as 600 million Samsung phones may be vulnerable to attacks that allow hackers to surreptitiously monitor the camera and microphone, read incoming and outgoing text messages, and install malicious apps, a security researcher said.
>
> The vulnerability is in the update mechanism for a Samsung-customized version of SwiftKey, available on the Samsung Galaxy S6, S5, and several other Galaxy models. When downloading updates, the Samsung devices don't encrypt the executable file, making it possible for attackers in a position to modify upstream traffic—such as those on the same Wi-Fi network—to replace the legitimate file with a malicious payload.

Is there a way for Samsung to patch this security fault by an update? Also, how can I find out if the Samsung phone I'm using is affected by this fault?

Comment: While a valid argument, I'm afraid we cannot answer what Sammy can or will do, or whether your provider goes along. You'd have to contact *them* to find out.

Comment: Heads up, since Samsung seems likely to provide [regular Android security update about once per month](http://www.samsungmobilepress.com/2015/08/10/Samsung-Announces-an-Android-Security-Update-Process-to-Ensure-Timely-Protection-from-Security-Vulnerabilities)